# Global table formatting, thin and think hlines, apply to all tables

Tags: tables, formatting

How can I define a table formatting style that will automatically be used throughout my document? For example, I understand that I can use the [caption package](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption?lang=en) to specify caption formatting used throughout the document. I think I would like to use the [booktabs package](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs?lang=en), but I will consider other established and maintained packages.

I am using Report document class with pdfLaTeX compiler in Overleaf.

Below is an example table format that I want to automatically apply to all tables (I know it's not pretty, but those are the specs from the Word template). (I included other formatting aspects in the example in case there is a package conflict or something that might matter.) Key table formatting elements are (1) bold lines at top and bottom of table and (2) thin lines between rows and columns. *How can I automatically apply all the `\specialrule` parts, instead of having to manually do it between every entry?* I looked at the *booktabs* documentation, but I did not understand how to set a global format. I am still learning LaTeX. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% set page dimensions
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}

% set paragraph dimensions
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}

% set Calibri-like font
\usepackage[sfdefault]{carlito}

% format headers
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}%
    {\normalfont\fontsize{18pt}{0pt}\bfseries}%
    {\thechapter}{0.5in}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{22pt}{18pt}


% format figure and table captions
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{capfnt}{\fontsize{11pt}{11pt}\selectfont #1}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period, singlelinecheck=false,%
    labelfont=bf, margin={0.25in, 0.3in}, skip=12pt,%
    font=capfnt, format=hang}

% format tables
\usepackage{booktabs}

%-------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

This is introduction paragraph. Some details, Table \ref{table:test}.


\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Test table.}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\specialrule{1.5pt}{0pt}{0pt}
ColA & ColB & ColC \\
\hline\hline
1 & alpha & x \\
\specialrule{0.5pt}{0pt}{0pt}
2 & beta & y \\
\specialrule{0.5pt}{0pt}{0pt}
3 & charlie & z \\
\specialrule{1.5pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\end{tabular}

\label{table:test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that automatic, global table formatting would require you to be consistent in your notation and `tabular` usage. For example, you will *always* have only one header line in the table. The reason why [`caption`](//ctan.org/pkg/caption) allows for easy global formatting stems from all the components that are used having a consistent name/hook. You have to follow the same guidelines when creating a table; for example, *always* end all lines with ``\\`` (say).

Comment: That makes sense I think, thank you